# How to remove this ParserError of contract in solidity langauge. I am using remix ide

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, contract-development, remix

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2; 
pragma solidity >=0.4.18;

contract Record {
    struct MedRecord {
        string password;
        string name;
        address patient;
        address[] doctor;
    }

    mapping(address => MedRecord) internal medRecords;

    address[] public recordList;

    function addRecord(address _key, string memory password, string memory name) public {
        address docs[] = new ;
        medRecords[_key] = MedRecord(password, name, _key, []);
        recordList.push(_key);
    }
    
    function remove(address _key) public {
        delete medRecords[_key];
    }
    
    // function contains(address _key) public view returns (bool) {
    //     return MedRecords[_key][0] != '';
    // }
    
    function getByKey(address _key) public view returns (MedRecord memory) {
        return medRecords[_key];
    }
}
```

And its throwing error:

> browser/tests/project/record.sol:18:21: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '[' address docs[] = new ;

The code looks fine to me.

Comment: What language do you know, in which the statement `type arr[] = new ;` is fine???

Answer (score 1):

You are simply initializing the address array incorrectly. Please try the following:

```
    function addRecord(address _key, string memory password, string memory name) public {
        address[] memory docs;
        medRecords[_key] = MedRecord(password, name, _key, docs);
        recordList.push(_key);
    }
```

Comment: then the next line becomes error

Comment: I have updated the answer.